# Video - sound - sensor capture in Java

Tags: java, video, sensors, jmf, javasound

I would like to develop an application which would be able to capture video from a webcam, capture sound from a mic and capture movement if a proximity sensor is available.

Initially I want it to run on windows but if able I might want to make it work on android later on.

I'm looking for something pretty straight forward and easy to understand.
My research has led me to Java Media Framework but it is too old and abandoned.
FMJ seems also old.
JavaCV appears to have poor documentation available.

My goal is to make a home detection app which uses the camera imagery, mic sound and sensors to detect and analyze home invasion.
I might take a leap and do it in .NET or other object oriented programming languages if
easier solutions present themselves.
How should I approach this, what are your suggestions?

Comment: *"I'm looking for something pretty straight forward and easy to understand"*  Then understand this.  Java for the desk-top is very 'hit & miss' when it comes to detecting sound sources.  On some machines, it cannot detect the mic. at all, let alone the sound stream from modern web-cams.  JMF is useless as a general purpose solution, since it was abandoned in 2003 ..there around.  In contrast it should be relatively easy to do in Android (much better sound/sensor integration). *"what are your suggestions?"*  For the J2SE side, hire a professional & hope for 80% coverage.

Answer (score 1):

- One Solution is use JavaCV. So you can develop your desktop application using java and later can be ported in to android with fewer changes. As you said JavaCV haven't rich documentation. But JavaCV is just a wrapper to a OpenCV. So you can read OpenCV documentaion and find the relevant method(function) names. The methods in JavaCV has almost same names as OpenCV. So you can try those methods in JavaCV.
- Next solution is use .NET to develop the system. There you can use
  [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) a rich library for .NET or [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com) .NET wrapper
  for OpenCV. But you will be facing a problem when creating the
  android app. Because you have to build it from scratch.